# Execute Python program using PHP

Tags: php, python

Can I simply execute Python program using PHP like this? (in a browser)

```
exec("python myProgram /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/somefile.xml");
```

or like this:

```
exec("/path/to/python path/to/myProgram /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/somefile.xml");
```

Is any of this method correct?

If not, what should be the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use PHP or Python only? Ie: You could translate the python program into php

Comment: I am generating XML string using PHP and then that needs to be passed to the python script as input. Like I do in my terminal windows: >>> myprogram myfile.xml .... basically the python script accepts a xml file and processed it to generate a font file.

Comment: What is this python program you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using `proc_open()` as suggested by mvds as you can't write to STDIN nor read from STDOUT with `exec()`/`shell_exec()`, as well as providing your own set of environment variable -`$_ENV`.

A sample snippet extracted from my code:

```
$process = proc_open(
    "{$command}",
    array(            
     array('pipe', 'r'),
     array('pipe', 'w'),
     array('pipe', 'w')
    ),
    $pipes,
    NULL,
    $_ENV
);

if(is_resource($process)){

    fwrite($pipes[0], $string);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $rt = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $rtErr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $exitCode = proc_close($process);

}
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 1):

if you want to capture output as well, use `proc_open` (full fd connectivity, i.e. input and output) or `popen` (either in- or output)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, why not?

Note that you are not executing this "in the browser" but rather on the server side, while the page is being pre-processed.

Consider that the page will not return until the `exec` has finished, so it really depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: basically I have a python program that I am able to run successfully like this in terminal (on mac): >>> myptogram myfile.xml ..... Now I am trying to achieve the same using PHP. If I do the way I showed in my post, will the result be same as my terminal window approach?

Comment: check this out tooo.... intresting http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: @ssdesign Yes, but why can't you just rewrite your python program in PHP? Because relying on exec() means you'll need to set up python wherever this code is going to run AND ensure you are allowed to use exec()

Comment: I have faced situations working on an environment with legacy code written in some other languages and I wish to execute them - than rewriting them in PHP.

Programmers are lazy ;)